# Capture BeforeItemCopy event in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2007

[image: Outlook 2007 Interface]
How to capture the copy event which is fired after clicking "Copy" list item from "Edit" menu, for a selected attachment item in the preview pane in Outlook ?

I tried binding following events but ended up, they only fire when mail items are selected

```
 ((Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_Event)Explorer).BeforeItemCopy += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_BeforeItemCopyEventHandler(ExplorerWrapper_BeforeItemCopy);
 ((Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_Event)Explorer).BeforeItemCut += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_BeforeItemCutEventHandler(ExplorerWrapper_BeforeItemCut);
```

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do ?
Please provide sample codes. (Outlook 2007)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the CommandBarButton control and subscribe to the [Click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864867.aspx) event. Try to play with the CommandBars property of the Explorer class from the Outlook object model and you will be able to find the target (Copy) control.